# JQuery Datatable memory leak under both IE and Chrome

Tags: datatable

My application is using Datatable which binds the data and event dynamically. When monitored from Developer tool in internet explorer one can see an increase in the total memory usage after each server successful response (increases approx. 29-35 MB). I tried solutions to free the DOM using jquery `remove()`, `empty()`, `detach()`, and `destroy()` methods but none stops the memory increase. Even destroying the datatable before request doesn't help. I also tried to delete the variables in the script, set the variables to `null`, and set the event bind to the datatable `off()`.

The code snippet from the js file is as follows

```
function LoadData(isReset) {
        var viewId = $jq('#ddlCategory').val();
        if (viewId == 'undefined' || viewId == null || viewId == '') {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            //Clear the variables and remove the datatable
            ClearFunction();

            dtAjaxCall = $jq.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Ajax/WorkListAjax.aspx/GetData",
                deferRender: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                timeout: 0,
                headers: { Connection: 'keep-alive' },
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "viewId": viewId
                }),
                success: function (response) {

                    //Clear the variables and remove the datatable
            ClearFunction();

                    result = response.d;

                    if (result.IsError) {
                        CustomConfirm("dialog-confirm", result.Message, "");
                    }
                    else if (result.Data != null) {

                        data01 = result.Data;
                        result.Data = null; //set the result.Data as null
                        tableHeaders = ''; //var to store Datatable headers
                        columns = []; //var to store Datatable columns
                        excludeFilters = [];//var to exclude the filters. 
                        bulkOperation = data01.BulkOperation; //var to store if bulk operation is required

                //Create the table header columns dynamically as configured in database
                        $jq.each(data01.Columns, function (i, val) {
                            if (val.HiddenColumn != "Y") {
                                tableHeaders += "<th>" + val.DisplayName + "</th>";
                                var col = { 'title': val.DisplayName, 'data': val.DataColumnName.toLowerCase() };
                                columns.push(col);
                            }
                            if (val.FilterColumn >= 0) {
                                excludeFilters.push(val.FilterColumn);
                            }
                        });

                        data = $jq.parseJSON(data01.Results); //result returned in ajax call
                        json = $jq.parseJSON(data01.WorkListJQStructure); //datatable configuration returned in ajax call

                        delete json["bAutoWidth"];

                        json.data = data;
                        json.columns = columns;

                        DisplayExportOptions(json.buttons, 'resultsTable', 'ulExportTo');

               //Add checkbox for each row in the data table
                        dtColumnDefinition = function (data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" data-id="' + data + '">';
                        }

                        json.aoColumnDefs[0].render = dtColumnDefinition;

                //Ajax call to save the datatable state state
                        dtSaveState = function (settings, data) {
                            $jq.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "Ajax/WorkListAjax.aspx/SaveState",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                async: true,
                                dataType: "json",
                                data: JSON.stringify({ "viewId": viewId, json: data }),
                                "success": function () {
                                },
                                error: function (request, status, error) {
                                    CustomConfirm("dialog-confirm", "An error occurred while processing your current request. Please try again", "");
                                }
                            });
                        }

                //Try destroying the existing instance
                        if ($jq.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#resultsTable')) {
                            $jq('#resultsTable').DataTable().destroy();
                        }

                        //Make the body empty
                        $jq('#resultsTable tbody').empty();
                        //Remove the datatable
                        $jq("#resultsTable").dataTable().remove();

                        //Datatable save state function call
                        json.stateSaveCallback = dtSaveState;

                        //Empty from the parent table of the datatable
                        $jq("#resultsTable_display").empty();

                        //Create the datatable header dynamically and add to the parent table
                        $jq("#resultsTable_display").append('<table id="resultsTable" class="display" style="width:100%;white-space: nowrap;"><thead><tr>' + tableHeaders + '</tr></thead></table>');

                        //bind the json and data to the datatable
                        SearchTable = $jq("#resultsTable").DataTable(json).rows().invalidate().draw();

                        //Set the event off before
                        $jq("#resultsTable").off();
                        //Set the event
                        $jq('#resultsTable').on('length.dt', function (e, settings, len) {
                            //code to set the height dynamically...
                        });

                        $jq("#resultsTable_display .dataTables_scrollHeadInner").css("width", "100%");
                        $jq("#resultsTable_display .dataTables_scrollHeadInner .dataTable").css("width", "100%");

                        BulkOpr(bulkOperation, SearchTable);

                        //reset the columns after binding the data
                        SearchTable.columns.adjust();

                        DataTableName = '#resultsTable';

                        $jq('#resultsTable').on('page.dt', function () {
                            info = SearchTable.page.info();
                            customHeight = 0;
                            customHeight = UserDefinedFields.CustomPageHeight(info, 40);
                            $jq('#Parent').attr('style', 'min-height:' + customHeight + 'px;');
                        });

                        $jq("a").removeClass("dt-button");
                    }
                    //set the variables null
                    json = null;
                    data01 = null;
                    data = null;
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    //do nothing...
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
        finally {
            //Clear the variables...
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------
    //method to clear the variables and datatables
    function ClearFunction()
    {
        //make all variables null
        dtAjaxCall = null;
        resultSearchTable = null;
        DataTableName = null;
        info  = null;
        customHeight = null;
        cells = null;
        selected = null;
        cBox = null;
        clist = null;
        dtSaveState = null;
        result = null;
        data01 = null;
        tableHeaders = null;
        columns = null;
        excludeFilters = null;
        bulkOperation = null;
        data = null;
        json = null;
        dtColumnDefinition = null;

        //clear dom objects
        $jq("#resultsTable").dataTable().remove();
        $jq("#resultsTable_display").dataTable().empty();
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We are refreshing a datatable in a polling method, and it seems to lock up the browser. I don't have an answer either.